# Unexpected scrolling behaviour when routing from modal context

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I am experiencing some interesting issue with my Angular4 application when try to re-route using modal dialog.

What I do:

on button click I call function that will show a modal dialog:

```
public resetAndBack() {
let that = this;
this.modalProcess(this.cancelModal,
  function () {
    that.isNewVer = false;
    that.router.navigate(['/doc/search']);
  });
}
```

for handling modal's events I have a 'generic' function:

```
private modalProcess(instance: any, scssCb: Function, errCb?: Function) {
instance.open()
  .then(function (resultPromise: any) {
    resultPromise.result.then((result: any) => {
      scssCb();
      this.logger.i('modal ok');
    }, function() {
      if (errCb)
        errCb();
      this.logger.i('modal rejected');
    });
  });
}
```

I have encapsulated modal dialogs into the separate class just for code clarity sake:

```
export class CancelConfirmModal {

    ctx: any;

    constructor(context: any) {
        this.ctx = context;
    }

    public open() {
        let mod = this.ctx.modal.alert()
            .size('lg')
            .showClose(true)
            .title('Zrušit zmeny ?')
            .body(`
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-md-12">
                         <div>Zrušiť zmeny na dokumente ?</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>`)
            .open();

        return mod;
    }
}
```

which is created in class constructor like you guess:

```
this.cancelModal = new CancelConfirmModal(this);
```

Now, what happens after clicking 'ok' one the modal (calling scss callback) is that application gets re-routed but vertical scroll bar disappears completely. on all the other pages that you can navigate over the application. Simply you can't scroll the page. It only helps to refresh whole page.

On the other hand, when I leave out `modalProcess` function and I call `that.router.navigate(['/doc/search']);` right after `resetAndBack` function call, it works properly.

So I would like you to teach me a bit what is technically going on and maybe what would be a better shape for what I'm trying to achieve.

Can you tell?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the modal window before redirecting.  This solved the same issue on the project I'm working on.